# What the Right way To Upload Very big length NSData to server?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I am uploading Image to server. Length Of NSData will depend On the size of image. if image is too big, NSData length will be 6798791 (length will vary). if image is small Request is getting Uploaded to server. if request it too big (Contains very big image) request is not getting uploaded. Below is request format of an image.

```
<vaayoo:message xmlns:vaayoo="http://www.vaayoo.com<vaayoo:ostype>iphone</vaayoo:ostype><vaayoo:osversion>8</vaayoo:osversion><vaayoo:deviceid>354043043430851</vaayoo:deviceid><vaayoo:sku>lite</vaayoo:sku><vaayoo:xmlversion>1.0</vaayoo:xmlversion></vaayoo:header><vaayoo:vaayoodata xmlns:vaayoo="http://www.vaayoo.com/version2/yooml" datatype="content" mobiletid="8DD7A158-FC05-4588-B4D6-39D93F10E504" formname="frm_reportupload" streamid="A58BFEAF-E566-4ddc-842D-F8C5976FC300"><vaayoo:event type="control_click" name="btn_submit"><vaayoo:action type="form.asyncsubmit" url="http://content.vaayoo.com/AppsPlatForm/PhotoReportCreatorService/PhotoReportCreator.svc/PhotoreportResponse" asyncurl="http://content.vaayoo.com/AppsPlatForm/ConentUploadService/1_1/MyuploadService.svc/UploadData"/></vaayoo:event><vaayoo:data type="formdata" collection="true"><vaayoo:input name="img_0" type="image" filename="01262013035548648.jpg" currentchunk="18" totalchunk="18">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</vaayoo:input><vaayoo:input name="txt_rpt_name" type="text" textmode="multiline">anil dairy</vaayoo:input></vaayoo:data></vaayoo:vaayoodata></vaayoo:message>
```

Below is the method which is writing the data to server.

```
-(BOOL)write:(NSData *)data toURI:(NSString *)URI
{
BOOL retVal = NO;
NSString* requestDataLengthString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", [data         length]];
NSLog(@"Data length is %@",requestDataLengthString);
NSLog(@"Urlis %@",URI);
NSRange range = [URI rangeOfString:@"http"];//Is http?  
if(range.location != NSNotFound) 
{   
    //Yes, http
    NSMutableURLRequest *httpRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:URI]];



    [httpRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [httpRequest setHTTPBody:data];


    [httpRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [httpRequest setValue:requestDataLengthString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:httpRequest delegate:self];

    [theConnection release];
    [httpRequest release];

    if (theConnection) 
    {
        receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
        retVal = YES;
    } 
    else 
    {                                            
        NSError *error = [NSError alloc];
        NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
            [error localizedDescription],
            [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
            [error release];

        retVal = NO;
    }

}                                            
return retVal;
```

}

What am i doing wrong in Write method ? it works fine for small images, but doesn't work for bigger images, not even getting any kind of exception if i try to upload big images. How to troubleshoot this problem. Help me out plz.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the asynchronous upload with NSURLConnection delegates? Probably the error might show up there. What language are you using for the webservice? It could be the setting on your webserver that makes it fail to upload big image. Try to see the maximum request length that is set on your server. If it's smaller than the image size, then it would fail.

Comment: according to this: `NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:httpRequest delegate:self];` he is using delegates

Comment: I havnt used asynchronous upload with NSURL Connection delegates. I will try with Asynchronous upload. I am using WCF (Rest service) with C#. the maximum request length the server supports for 10Mb, but images are less than 8Mb.

Comment: Hey tyegah, I tried uploading image asynchronously,i.e 
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:httpRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {}, i am able to upload image having size upto 2.5Mb, after that i am getting empty response.

Comment: i had given timeoutInterval as 1000.0. do i need to increase it to a still higher number?

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply. but what i meant with asynchronous NSURL connection delegates is these methods you should implement like the ones in this link 

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

in the method connectionDidFailWithError you should see the error there if the connection fails. and you can see the data received in the method connectionDidReceiveData. and try also increasing your timeout interval.

Hope it helps. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSTimeoutInterval and try its working:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:1000.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
 [httpRequest setHTTPBody:data];
```

Use:

```
NSInputStream *stream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:filePath];
request setHTTPBodyStream:stream];
```

Apple has an example of [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).